# mPDF - Image not appearing in PDF when inserted via HTML

Tags: php, html, image, pdf, mpdf

I'm using mPDF to create a PDF with PHP. When trying to insert an image with HTML it is not appearing in the generated PDF.

I'm trying to insert the image like this:

```php
$pdf_html = '<div style="font-family: sans-serif;">
                <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/1/11/Test-Logo.svg/783px-Test-Logo.svg.png" width="100%" height="100%" />
                <br>
                <p>Testing testing.</p>
              </div>';

$pdf->WriteHTML($pdf_html);
```

The rest of the content works fine but the image isn't appearing. Where am I going wrong?

**UPDATE**

I've found that I can embed image fine if I convert it to it's data URI (e.g. using https://ezgif.com/image-to-datauri/). This is fine for static images but I need to embed some of them dynamically using the URL. I tried using the following function to convert images to their data URI but this doesn't seem to work either:

```php
function image_data_encode($image){

  $data = file_get_contents($image);
  $base64 = base64_encode($data);
  $data_uri = "data:image/png;base64,".$base64;

  return $data_uri;

}
```

Then in my PDF HTML code I would do something like:

```php
$pdf_html = '<div style="font-family: sans-serif;">
                <img src="' . image_data_encode("https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/1/11/Test-Logo.svg/783px-Test-Logo.svg.png") . '" width="100%" height="100%" />

                <br>
                <p>Testing testing.</p>
              </div>';

$pdf->WriteHTML($pdf_html);
```

As per comments and answer, I've:

- Checked that curl is enabled
- Tried escaping the double quotes
- Checked error logs (no errors)
- Tried using an absolute path to the image file

I'm developing this locally on my machine and can access the image files via my browser so I assume they should be accessible from my dev environment

Comment: Could you ensure you have php-curl extension installed and enabled?

Comment: You will need to escape your double quotes, for example like this width=\"100%\"

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions, I've tried these but it still doesn't work (see question update)

Comment: from that environment, can you do a `wget <image>`? will that download the file?

Comment: Yes, it downloads the file

Comment: Try leveraging https://mpdf.github.io/installation-setup/logging.html, see if it does not push you in the right direction.